# PHP Table Data Show Results Vertically not Horizontally

Tags: php, html-table

I'm really frustrated.. I really need to show this table right. How can I set this code to show table vertically like this:

1 - 4 - 7

2 - 5 - 8

3 - 6 - 9

And not like this:

1 - 2 - 3 - 4

5 - 6 - 7 - 8

9 - ... ect

```php
<?php

$PNG_WEB_DIR = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'temp/';

wp_mkdir_p($PNG_WEB_DIR);

$cols = $this->settings['cols'];
$rows = $this->settings['rows'];
$label_number = 0;

// die($_GET['order_ids']);
$order_ids = explode(',',$_GET['ids']);
$order_count = count($order_ids);
$labels_per_page = $cols*$rows;
$page_count = ceil(($order_count)/$labels_per_page);

for ($page=0; $page < $page_count; $page++) {
    echo '<table class="address-labels" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">';
    $last_height = 0;
    $current_height = $current_width = 0;
    $current_row = 0;

    for ($label=0; $label < $labels_per_page; $label++) { 
        $label_number++;
        $current_col = (($label_number-1) % $cols)+1;

        if ($current_col == 1) {
            $last_height = $current_height;
            $last_width = 0;
            $current_row++;
            echo '<tr class="label-row">';
        }

        if ( $label_number > $this->offset && isset($order_ids[$label_number - $this->offset - 1]) ) {
            $order_id = $order_ids[$label_number - $this->offset - 1];
        } else {
            $order_id = '';         
        }

        $current_width = round( $current_col * (100/$cols) );
        $width = $current_width - $last_width;
        $last_width = $current_width;

        $current_height = round( $current_row * (100/$rows) );
        $height = $current_height - $last_height;

        printf('<td width="%s%%" height="%s%%" class="label"><div class="label-wrapper">', $width, $height);
        // because we are also looping through the empty labels,
        // we need to check if there's an order for this label
        if (!empty($order_id)) {
            // get label data from order
            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

            // replace placeholders
            $label_data = isset($this->settings['address_data'])? nl2br( $this->settings['address_data'] ): '[shipping_address]';
            $label_data = $this->make_replacements( $label_data, $order );

            echo '<div class="address-block">';
            echo '<div class="addrress_show">';

            // process label template to display content
            echo $label_data; 
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="clearb"></div>';
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo '&nbsp;';
        }
        echo '</div></td>';

        if ($current_col == $cols) {
            echo '</tr>';
        }

    }
    echo '</table>';
}
        // shpt_after_page hook
                do_action( 'shpt_after_page' );
        ?>
```

Comment: What is the original data structure? An array of arrays - ie: multidimensional array?

Comment: This is a part of a free Wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-order-address-print/

I hope it helps with your question, I'm new with this...

Comment: no, that doesn't really help

Comment: All the settings are in the back-end (rows, columns etc), But this code represent the table before printing..

Comment: I know it should be easy, but i can't figure it out.

Comment: we need to know the data that you loop through to compose the table is structured

Comment: It's taking the names and city's from the latest orders and putting them in a print page (3 columns/27 rows per page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't know your raw data structure which you use to loop through it and produce the table, I presumed it as one-dimensional array and you want to print the table as 3 columns as you said, to see in action here's a [**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/xir4-t6gz) - *hit run to execute it* - this will work for any array length as long as columns is 3, the rows is dynamic

**PHP:** *Updated for naming purpose*

```
<?php
    $table = '<table class="address-labels" width="30%" border="0" cellpadding="0">';
    $dataArr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16, 17);
    $colNum = 3;
    $rowNum = ceil(count($dataArr)/$colNum);
    for($i=0; $i < $rowNum; $i++){
        $x1 = isset( $dataArr[$i] ) ? $dataArr[$i] : '-';
        $x2 = isset( $dataArr[$i + $rowNum] ) ? $dataArr[$i + $rowNum] : '-';
        $x3 = isset( $dataArr[$i + 2 * $rowNum] ) ? $dataArr[$i + 2 * $rowNum] : '-';
        $table .= '<tr><td>' . $x1 . '</td><td>' . $x2 . '</td><td>' . $x3 . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $table .= '</table>';
    echo $table;

?>
```

---

**EDIT:**
Now if you want to change the column number, like set it to 5 for example, you need to do the following:

1st - set `$colNum = 5;` 
2nd - add more variables to hold the values like, *considering it is 5 columns:

```
 $x4 = isset( $dataArr[$i + 3 * $rowNum] ) ? $dataArr[$i + 3 * $rowNum] : '-';
 $x5 = isset( $dataArr[$i + 4 * $rowNum] ) ? $dataArr[$i + 4 * $rowNum] : '-';
```

and don't forget to increase the multiplier `* $rowNum`

then for each extra column you add you need to add `<td></td>` like:

```
'<td>' . $x4 . '</td><td>' . '</td><td>' . $x5 . '</td><td>' . '</td>'
```

Here's another [**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ba7e-5cmu) showing the above for 5 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's in pure php

```
<?php 

$cols = 3;
$data = range(1,29);


// classic 
$index = 1;
foreach($data as $el)
{
    echo $el.' ';  if ($index % $cols ==0) echo '<br/>';
    $index++;
}

echo '<br/><br/>';

// special
$rows = $cols ;
$cols = floor(count($data)/$cols);

for($row = 0 ; $row < $rows; $row++){

    for ($index = $row; $index < count($data); $index += $rows)
    echo $data[$index].' ';
    echo '<br/>';

}
```